# ClassNotFound ByteCodeProvider with iReport/Hibernate connection

Tags: hibernate, jasper-reports, ireport

On my hibernate application, I want to use jasperreports for some reports. I use iReport for designing.
When I want to open an hibernate connection (or a spring/hibernate connection) in iReport, I have a ClassNotFoundException. In the logs I see that it concerns the class org.hibernate.bytecode.BytecodeProvider. I don't understand why, because it's a fresh install.
Is anybody has a solution ?

I use the 4.7.0 version of iReport.

Comment: Do you have ***hibernate3.jar*** in `ireport\modules\ext1 folder? Is this folder is already in *iReport*'s classpath? –

Comment: Yes. I made a fresh reinstall, including drop HOME/.iReport directory, and it works. Maybe it was a configuration problem. Thanks